# @yield and @section problem while loading multiple sections in a single layout

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel and I'm learning about blade system.
I want to have a index page with several sections which are defined in different files.

In this case, I have a index.blade.php, and I want to have two sections, one is called "panel" and another section is called "tasks" in my index.blade.php.

The sections are defined and coded in panel.blade.php and create.panel.php.
Also, all the three files are located in "view/todos/" directory.
The code I'm writing is the code below:

index.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    @yield('panel')
    @yield('tasks')
</body>
</html>
```

For panel.blade.php I have:

```
@extends('todos.index')

@section('panel')
<!--- Panel Content --->
@endsection
```

And for create.blade.php I have something like this:

```
@extends('todos.index')

@section('tasks')
<!--- Task Content --->
@endsection
```

And finally, in web.php, I have:

```
Route::get('/todos',function(){
    return view('todos.index');
});
```

Whenever I try to access the "/todos" address, it just show me a blank page.

I tried several ways by changing the view("todos.index") to view("todos.panel") or view("todos.create"), but it just shows me one of the sections and not the other one.

Comment: you would return the view that extends the layout, that is how the sections get filled usually ... perhaps you want those 2 files to be includes (subviews) instead?

Comment: @lagbox Yes, The thing I want is something like the vue components, which are defined in different files and used in a single layout. I was thinking about using "@include" but, is there a way to do it using "@yield" and "@section"?

Comment: if you wanted to use the component system instead you could, instead of an include you use the component syntax and what ever else is involved with registering them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand you logic well. But seems like you misunderstood how `@yield` works.

Instead you can use @include like in this part of the documentation : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#including-subviews

I was thinking of something using the **Aliasing Includes** subpart a few scroll down from the main part I linked just above.

Tell me if it helped you

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems I was wrong about the usage of `@yield`. What I need to do, is to use `@include` and laravel components here. Looks like `@yield` and `@section` cannot define several different sections in a single page, like what components do.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Happy it helped ! Keep going ! It is practice makes perfect ;)

Answer (score 1):

If someone still need some help with this, let me show how I solved that:

**My template**

```
@include('common.header')
    @yield('menu')
    @yield('content')
    @yield('another-stuff')
@include('common.footer')
```

**Extending the template**

```
@extends('common.template')
@section('menu')
    @include('common.menu')
@endsection

@section('content')
    @include('content')
@endsection

@section('another-stuff')
    @include('another-stuff')
@endsection
```

And the html + php code (menu, content and another-stuff), as you can see, I separated in its own files, making the content management easy. Enjoy! o/